# Sum rule for Modified Bessel Function

Tags: sequences-and-series

Answer to this question will greatly be appreciated if somebody solve it. Mathematica does not give the answer
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\frac{1}{2}I_{n-1}(x)+\frac{1}{2}I_{n+1}(x)-I_{n}(x)}{n^2}$$

Comment: To be honest, I can't find a question, in your question.

Comment: I mean closed form solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $I_n(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{x\cos\theta}\cos(n\theta)\,d\theta $ the given series equals

$$ S(x)=\frac{1}{12\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{x\cos\theta}\left(-1+\cos\theta\right)\left(2 \pi ^2-6 \pi  \theta +3 \theta^2\right)\,d\theta $$
by well-known Fourier series. This does not simplify much further but it is simple to approximate numerically:

$$S(x)\approx \frac{\pi e^x}{6}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{-x\theta^2/2}e^{-\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{\pi^2}\right)(\pi-\theta)^2}\,d\theta $$
and by Laplace's method:
$$ S(x) \approx \frac{\pi e^x}{6}e^{-\frac{\pi ^2 \left(12+\pi ^2\right) x}{2 \left(12+\pi ^2 (1+2 x)\right)}}\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{6}{\pi^2}}}. $$

Comment: Great. Thanks! With your General S(x), I can now proceed my problem.