# Closed form solution of Series contaning modified Bessel Function

Tags: sequences-and-series

The closed form solution of the series is
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty I_n(x) = \frac{(e^x-I_0(x))}{2}$$
What is the closed form solution of this one $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{I_n(x)}{n^2}$$
Of course, it is a convergent series.

Comment: Is for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes, for all x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the same technique used [in the answer to your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2362543/sum-rule-for-modified-bessel-function),
$$ I_n(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{x\cos\theta}\cos(n\theta)\,d\theta \tag{1} $$
$$ \forall \theta\in(0,\pi),\qquad \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos(n\theta)}{n^2}=\frac{2 \pi ^2-6 \pi  \theta+3 \theta^2}{12}\tag{2} $$
lead to:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{I_n(x)}{n^2} = \frac{1}{12\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}e^{x\cos\theta}\left(2 \pi ^2-6 \pi  \theta+3 \theta^2\right)\,d\theta.\tag{3} $$

I do not think the RHS of $(3)$ has a nice closed form, but for $|x|\ll 1$ we may exploit Taylor series and for $|x|\gg 1$ we may exploit [Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method) to derive accurate numerical approximations.

Comment: How do you find that specific $I_n(x)$? I started studying Fourier series recently. That's why I am curious. The structure looks close to every term of a Fourier series.

Comment: @MANMAID: $(1)$ is a well-known integral representation - http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html

Comment: @MANMAID: these notes are well-written: www.math.psu.edu/papikian/Kreh.pdf

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Can you please provide a reference (2)? Since cosine is periodic, I assume your formula can be somehow expanded suitably for a range outside 0,$\pi$. When I approach that by twice integrating $e^{i n x}$ and taking real part, I get a much complicated expression.

Comment: @Srini: have a look at www.math.tulane.edu/~vhm/fourier.pdf