# Closed form of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1} \sin(kx)}{k^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1} \sin(kx)}{k^2}$$

Jack D'Aurizio replied to a related question in a comment of mine here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2362895/335418

The linked document shows formulas involving cosines for even powers and sines for odd powers. So I couldn't use what was in that document to arrive at this. When I plot an approximation of this sum in Wolfram-alpha, it "seems" to be a converging at all points. Is there a closed form for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To derive such formulas, note that

$$\ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}n$$

Let $x=e^{i\theta}$ and you get

$$\ln(1+e^{i\theta})=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{e^{ni\theta}}n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta)}n$$

From here, take real and imaginary parts to get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(n\theta)}n=\frac12\ln(1+2\cos(\theta))\\\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(n\theta)}n=\frac{\pi-\theta}2$$

Which hold for $\theta\in(0,\pi)$.  Integrate with respect to $\theta$ and use sum of angles formulas to get expressions you want.

Answer (score 3):

This is related to the [Clausen Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function).

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} \frac{\sin(kz)}{k^2} = -\operatorname{Cl}_2(z + \pi) = \int_0^{z+\pi} \log \left|2\sin\frac{x}{2}\right|\, dx$$

Answer (score 0):

This is also related to polylogarithms functions
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k+1} \frac{\sin(kz)}{k^n} =\frac{i}{2} \left(\text{Li}_n\left(-e^{i
   x}\right)-\text{Li}_n\left(-e^{-i x}\right)\right)$$